# How does join() work?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a JS quiz and stumbled uppon this question.

> *What does this function return?*
>
> ```
> function Batman()
> {
>   return Array(4).join("lol" - 2) + " Batman!";
> }
> ```

This actually happens to return **NaNNaNNaN Batman!** which i found rather funny.
But why does it return exactly this? i mean it stores NaN 3 times and suddenly it skips that and puts batman in the final index. While afaik the exact same thing happens for each array index.

Comment: I was redirected here from SE: programming puzzles. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37085/why-does-this-function-returns-this

Comment: You might want to search up on what [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) does. That might give you an explanation.

Comment: Because there are four `undefined`s in the array which are joined by three `NaN`s.

Comment: I've edited your question so that it's appropriate for SO, but had to guess at a title that corresponds to your actual question.  Please feel free to edit the title if my guess is incorrect.

Comment: Isn't this what the spoiler tag is all about? Rolled back once, have it your way then Oli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not getting what you want to do.

Your function works like bellow.

```
Array(4) //retruns [undefined × 4]
```

You are saying

```
[undefined × 4].join("lol"-2)
```

Here because `"lol"-2` returns `NaN` it will return `"NaNNaNNaN"`

And after this you are appendig the result to `" Batman!"` so the last result will be

```
"NaNNaNNaN Batman!"
```

Comment: I am not doing anything besides reproducing this quiz question, just want to know why. Thanks you, it's actually all in the join. Still not very clear why it returns NaN only 3 times instead of 4.

Comment: That's how `join` works, it adds delimitor between two elements @MennoGouw

Comment: @MennoGouw It **joins** the elements of the array, adding the string **between** them, and does not **append** to each element. `["A", "B", "C"].join("foo")` is `"AfooBfooC"`.

Comment: There is no `[undefined x 4]`. The expression `Array(4)` is the same as `new Array(4)`, it creates a new **empty** array with a length of 4. There are no members, that's why there are only 3 NaNs (one between each non–existent member).

Comment: @RobG but `join` looks for the first four members, at indices 0, 1, 2 and 3. And those are `undefined`. It's irrelevant *why* they are undefined.

Comment: @RobG I agree with you, I did in chrome console, and it gives like bellow.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant—the elements are undefined in the sense that they never existed (i.e. are not defined), rather than exist with a value of *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

The code tries to subtract 2 from `"lol"`. But because `"lol"` isn't a number, the result isn't a number either; that gets represented internally by a value known as "Not a Number", or "NaN" for short.

You've got several of those in an array. When you try to join them all together as strings, and add on " Batman!" to the end, the NaN gets converted to its most sensible string representation, which is just `NaN`.

So you end up with several copies of "`NaN`", followed by "`Batman!`".

See [Wikipedia's entry on NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Array(4).join("lol" - 2)` returns a string consisting of 3 NaN. The `+` operator concatenates " Batman!" at the end of the previous string (it does not append any item to any array, since join() returns a string). So, the function returns that funny sentence.